# Import Projects: is there a way to set root dir to workspace_loc

Tags: eclipse, filepath

In the dialog box for

```
File->Import->General->Existing Projects
```

The root directory defaults to the top level of my windows machine. Is there a short hand for the select root directory using `workspace_loc` or a preference to set the default behavior of this dialog box?

Currently, I cut and paste or, just drill down manually in the dialog box but wanted to check if there was a better way.